# CUDA crash on Blender Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, error

When ever I try to render my animation it crashes after 30-50 frames. Its a fairly simple scene, there are 642,026 triangles. I have intel i7 and a GTX 1650. The materials or the lighting are not complex at all. Just normal PBR materials. The error is "CUDA error as cuCtxCreate()" after that some gibberish that I cant remember, but it said it was something because of Optix denoising, which I used for rendering. My GPU can handle pretty complex scenes. I know I can increase the TDR time, but what is the root cause because my computer or GPU isn't getting hanged. I am constantly checking the task manager to see how much GPU is used, and it is not much, its betwee 1% and 20%

Comment: Crashes in blender are almost always related to memory management. What is the VRAM usage like on your GPU when this is happening? Is the performance demand of your render exceeding your VRAM capacity? Also, when you say "normal PBR materials", how many of them are there, and at what resolution (2k, 4k, etc...)? Hi-res PBR's can eat up VRAM pretty fast.

Comment: If the initialization for rendering takes too long the OS might consider the GPU driver unresponsive and reset it. That's why the TDR delay is important on Windows. See explanation [here](https://docs.substance3d.com/spdoc/gpu-drivers-crash-with-long-computations-128745489.html).

Comment: I have fixed the issue, what I did was I closed Blender and then restarted my computer. Then it was able to render the rest of the animation. However thanks for your time!